# Issue with global and local scope in this code?

Tags: javascript, scope, closures

I am testing this code to ensure that user only adds a number and when he does, I want to alert that number. 
If i test with only letters on first prompt and then change to a number on the second prompt, it still gives me a NaN. 
how to rectify this:

```
var mynum = prompt("Enter the number you wish");

function isitanumber(numb){
    while (isNaN(numb) == true){
        numb = prompt("Please add a valid number");
    } 
}

isitanumber(mynum);
alert("The number you have added is " + mynum);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best guess would be that your `mynum` variable doesn't get the updated value once user enters any text at initial `prompt`. So I would suggest you to `return` the value everytime back from the calling function and update your global variable.

```js
var mynum = prompt("Enter the number you wish");

function isitanumber(numb) {
  while (isNaN(numb)) {
    return parseInt(prompt("Please add a valid number")); //return
  }
}

mynum = isitanumber(mynum); //update the variable

alert("The number you have added is " + mynum);
```

You could also use `do-while` in this case as below:

```js
var mynum;
do{
    mynum = parseInt(window.prompt("Please enter a number", ""));
}while(isNaN(mynum));

alert("The number you have added is " + mynum);
```

Comment: Thanks Guruprasad! It all worked out. I used the return method. Could I please ask why the return method worked? I thought return breaks the loop and won;t let it run after the first time? is this correct?

Comment: Its like everytime when user enters a non-digit value then we are returning the prompt itself which again does a recursion until a valid num is entered. So even though it returns it gets back there with a prompt.

Answer (score 2):

Your code should work fine. You forgot to grab the value from your second prompt though. This could work:

```
var mynum = prompt("Enter the number you wish");

function isitanumber(numb){
    while (isNaN(numb) == true){
        numb = prompt("Please add a valid number");
    }
    //This sets the value you are displaying to the new input
    mynum = numb;
 }

isitanumber(mynum);

alert("The number you have added is " + mynum);
```

Here is this code running: https://jsfiddle.net/ruvn2uf0/

Comment: Might be nice to clean it up to remove the setting of a global from within a function.

Comment: Thanks guys! it helped greatly!